# How to setup /etc/host in Ubuntu to have ip 192.168.X.X

Tags: 14.04, hosts

im using Ubuntu 14.4. my Ubuntu server IP is 10.20.0.25

how to setup my server to have ip 192.168.X.X when other device want to communicate with the server.
Below is my configuration. please advice

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   acs
10.20.0.25  www.acs.com
192.168.2.2 www.acs.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It you want other devices to see your server with the 192.168.x.x address then you need to define another interface with that 192 address.  Obviously these would need to be local devices.  I fthat is what you ask, then the /etc/hosts table is not part of the solution.

All that the hosts file does is relate an IP to a host name, so from your host is you went to http://acs/ the hosts file would resoolve that name (acs) to the hosts file defined address, 127.0.1.1,  If you put www.acs.com in the resolution would be the 10.20 IP.  Having multiple lines in etc/hosts with the same hostname is not good.  BUT, the hosts file resolves names locally so you do not need DNS.  It does not resolve external names to get to your server.